# How to show selected value from database in dropdown and selected automatice user department using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to when the user login and wants to create a post and the user department is selected automatically in the dropdown list.

Error:

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

this my code:

```
 <select name="president" class=" form-control">
   @foreach ($presidents as $key => $president)
   <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ $user->id === $president->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $president }}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

My controller

```
public function create()
{
    $presidents = DB::table("presidents")->pluck("P_name","id");
    return view('planout.create',compact( 'presidents'));
}
```

President Model:

```
   public function planouts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Planout' ,'planout_id');
    }
```

PlanOut Model:

```
    public function presidents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(President::class);
    }
```

Each user belongs to a department. When I create a user, I select a directory for the user. I want the relevant department to be automatically selected whenever a user publishes an article.

Planouts Table:

```
  Schema::create('planouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('quarter');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('0');
            $table->tinyInteger('active')->default('0');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        Schema::create('planout_president', function (Blueprint $table)                  {
            $table->integer('planout_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('president_id')->unsigned();
            $table->primary(['planout_id','president_id']);
        });
```

User Table:

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('fatherName')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('phone_no')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(false);
            $table->text('sign');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
 Schema::create('president_user', function (Blueprint $table)                  {
            $table->integer('president_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->primary(['president_id','user_id']);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Auth::user()->id` instead of `$user->id`

```
<select name="president" class=" form-control">
       @foreach ($presidents as $key => $president)
       <option value="{{ $key }}" {{ Auth::user()->id === $key ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $president }}</option>
     @endforeach
    </select>
```

Comment: I have also this erorr `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

Comment: Check `dd($presidents);` before `@foreach`

Comment: I check it resulte is  `^ Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1717 ▼
  #items: array:50 [▼
    1 => "Ghazni"
    2 => "Ghor"
    3 => "Bamiyan"
    4 => "Parwan" ] }`

Comment: `{{ Auth::user()->id === $key ? 'selected' : '' }}` instead of $president->id

Comment: It is worked
But the department that is related to the logged-in user is not selected.
A department that is not relevant to the user is selected by default

Comment: print these two variables and see what you have. Auth::user()->id , $key and then check for conditions.